# Deleting previous row

Tags: stata

I have the following data:

```
n  v1 v2

n1 1  A
n2 1  B
n3 1  C
n4 2  C
n5 1  D
n6 1  D 
n7 1  E
```

How do I delete the row just previous to `v1==2`? That is only delete `n3`.

I have tried the following command but obviously it does not work:

```
. drop [_n-1] if v1==2
weights not allowed
r(101);
```

Comment: `drop if v1[_n+1] == 2` should work for this example.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me:

```
clear

input str2 n v1 str1 v2
n1 1 A
n2 1 B
n3 1 C
n4 2 C
n5 1 D
n6 1 D 
n7 1 E
end

bysort v2 (v1): drop if v1 == 1 & v1[_N] == 2

list, separator(0)

     +--------------+
     |  n   v1   v2 |
     |--------------|
  1. | n1    1    A |
  2. | n2    1    B |
  3. | n4    2    C |
  4. | n5    1    D |
  5. | n6    1    D |
  6. | n7    1    E |
     +--------------+
```